# bottom-to-top JQuery animation not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I’m having trouble with animating a div going from bottom to top. It works fine in Firefox but acts weird in Chrome. My guess is that is has to do with “top” getting animated and not “bottom” but I have no idea to get around this.

[JSFiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/mp4gfz1z/1/)

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#animate").click(function() {

$("#two").animate(

 {
  
  top: "100" 


 }, 1000);
    
    });

   });
```

```css
html, body { height:100%; }

#container {
position: relative;
width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #ccc;
height: 100%;
clear:both;
}

#left {
position: relative;
width:25%;
max-width: 300px;
float:left;
height: 100%; 
background: blue;

}

#right {

width:50%;
max-width: 649px;
float:right;
height: 100%; 
background: red;

}

#one {
position: absolute;
width:100%;
height: 100px; 
background: black;
top:0;

}

#two {

width:100%;
height: 100px; 
background: green;
position: absolute;
bottom:0;



}
```

```html
<div id="container">

 <div id="left">

  <div id="one">
 </div>

 <div id="two">
  <button id="animate">button</button>
 </div>

 </div>

 <div id="right">
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the provided html/css, explicitly defining the direction from the bottom should work in both Firefox and Chrome:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#animate").click(function() {

$("#two").animate(
    {
        bottom: "+=" + (parseInt($("#container").css("height"),10) - parseInt($("#one").css("height"),10) - parseInt($("#two").css("height"),10))
    }, 1000);

    });//animate

   });//Doc ready
```

This may not be the ideal solution for what you're trying to accomplish, but it's a workaround if there is no issue with deriving the number of pixels from the bottom using the heights of the container and the above element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I've solved it with setting top:100%; instead of bottom:0; for the #two-div.